# Performing image search with tags

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

Hi i have a database but can't seem to come up with a technique to searching for images on on my project my database structure is as shown below.

Images Table

image_id (PK) | category | thumb | preview | author

Image Tags Table

img_id (FK) | tag_name

The whole idea is for when a user fills the text box and hits enter, my php script uses the explode function to convert the value of the request by white-space into an array and then loop through each found value while making search on the database (image tags table) for a tag name that has a value like the request and joining the images table where the (FK) is equal to the (PK).

Am actually looking for a more efficient and workable method to doing it my

This is my code (php/query).

```
   $keywords = Input::get("keywords");

   $keywordsExploded = explode(" ", $keywords);

    for ($i=0; $i < count($keywordsExploded); $i++) { 

        $searchKey = $keywordsExploded[$i];

        $search = DB::table('image_tags')
                    ->leftJoin('images', 'images.image_id', '=', 'img_id')
                    ->where('tag_name','like','%'.$searchKey.'%')
                    ->get();

        $imageResult[] = $search;
    }

    $imageResult = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $imageResult)));
```

This is my output when i var dump.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [img_id] => 8045eb05de1f6b72824f2bfd2fc972c1
                    [tag_name] => Fine girls
                    [image_id] => 8045eb05de1f6b72824f2bfd2fc972c1
                    [category] => Family
                    [license] => Limited Utility (LU)
                    [author] => Daniel Barde
                    [thumb] => assets/downloads/img/thumb/2413759e3bdebf51b8bf215bc82018d4_thumb.jpg
                    [prv] => assets/downloads/img/prv/00eead497c552ab309ab66294cf5c758_P.jpg
                    [date_uploaded] => 01 - 23 - 2014
                    [time_uploaded] => 1390517578
                    [search_id] => 1390513134
                    [usage_policy] => 
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [img_id] => c57d2e6f501670487fb5a5e2a016b5c1
                    [tag_name] => Fine girls
                    [image_id] => c57d2e6f501670487fb5a5e2a016b5c1
                    [category] => Fashion
                    [license] => Exclusive Utility (E
                    [author] => Daniel Barde
                    [thumb] => assets/downloads/img/thumb/c31598650ec51e6dd5725b2711920e91_thumb.jpg
                    [prv] => assets/downloads/img/prv/fa1872139b4f53a840e94d7ceca1911e_P.jpg
                    [date_uploaded] => 01 - 25 - 2014
                    [time_uploaded] => 1390657236
                    [search_id] => 1390652792
                    [usage_policy] => 
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [img_id] => dfc7ec5aae7ce3b4397c57d4167b6417
                    [tag_name] => legs
                    [image_id] => dfc7ec5aae7ce3b4397c57d4167b6417
                    [category] => Lifestyle
                    [license] => Broad Utility (BU)
                    [author] => Lifestyle
                    [thumb] => assets/downloads/img/thumb/97f4517f6d5bdad880151d940da638d6_thumb.jpg
                    [prv] => assets/downloads/img/prv/fb7402b93ce27fe6e93e5578571e02fe_P.jpg
                    [date_uploaded] => 01 - 25 - 2014
                    [time_uploaded] => 1390656768
                    [search_id] => 1390652324
                    [usage_policy] => 
                )

        )

)
```

This is the code in my view.

```
 @if(!empty($imgs))
    @for ($i=0; $i < count($imgs) ; $i++)
        <div class="span3 transition metal">
            <figure class="top-img">
                <img src="{{$backend_url}}{{$imgs[0][$i]->thumb}}" alt="{{$imgs[0][$i]->category}}" id='img{{$imgs[0][$i]->image_id}}'>
                <figcaption class="img-meta">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span8">
                            <a href="{{$base_url}}image/{{$imgs[0][$i]->search_id}}" class="img-id">#{{$imgs[0][$i]->search_id}}</a>
                            <a href="#" class="img-tags">{{$imgs[0][$i]->category}}</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="span4">
                            <a href="#" class="btn download-btn"><i class="icon-download"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </figcaption> <!-- end img-meta -->
                <div class="roll-over" data-source='{{$imgs[0][$i]->image_id}}'>
                    <a href="#" class="btn"><span class="bucket"><i class='icon-shopping-cart'></i></span></a>
                </div> <!-- end roll-over -->
            </figure> <!-- end top-img -->
        </div><!--  end span3 -->
@endfor
@endif
```

Comment: First of all show us your current code / query then we will see what can be done to improve it

Comment: How does this tag you are using look like?

Comment: @Marcel the tag  is the string gotten from the users input then searched for in the database based on tags already input by admin for each image

Comment: what do you mean by "more efficient and workable method"? What would you like to do that right now you are not able to?

Comment: @clod986 This methos stores the returned array of data in another array ($imageResult[]) making difficult to loop through, also, this method does not allow me to display all found record, it only display the first two.

Comment: have you considered declaring $imageResult as a [Collection](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections)? The other option, if you don't want an array, is to send a Response::json($search) at the end of every loop

Comment: @clod986 it still displays only two out of the whole result, would you like me to show you the output on print_r?

Comment: two questions: are you sure there should be more than 2 results? have you tried doing a var_dump of selected items (past the second result)? I'm not sure, but I believe var_dump doesn't return everything, if the lines are too many

Comment: Yes @clod986 i did a var_dumb that showed me all results and there are 4 results when i var_dump but when i run the loop it only whows two results.

Comment: Can you update with the code on the view?

Comment: @clod986 have added both the view and the var_dump output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
 @if(!empty($imgs))
    @foreach($imgs as $tag)
        @foreach($tag as $image)
        <div class="span3 transition metal">
            <figure class="top-img">
                <img src="{{$backend_url}}{{$image->thumb}}" alt="{{$image->category}}" id='img{{$image->image_id}}'>
                <figcaption class="img-meta">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span8">
                            <a href="{{$base_url}}image/{{$image->search_id}}" class="img-id">#{{$image->search_id}}</a>
                            <a href="#" class="img-tags">{{$image->category}}</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="span4">
                            <a href="#" class="btn download-btn"><i class="icon-download"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </figcaption> <!-- end img-meta -->
                <div class="roll-over" data-source='{{$image->image_id}}'>
                    <a href="#" class="btn"><span class="bucket"><i class='icon-shopping-cart'></i></span></a>
                </div> <!-- end roll-over -->
            </figure> <!-- end top-img -->
        </div><!--  end span3 -->
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
 @endif
```

If this works, it means you were skipping one of the two loops. Please note how I changed your `for` into `foreach` statement; I don't position myself as an experienced coder, but I like to keep the variables more readable instead of writing `$imgs[$i][$j]->something`

Comment: you are a great guy thanks for helping me out all the way, this method worked out neatly at a go, this my twitter handle if we could connect and stay in touch can also be of help to you one day. at mrbarde2k

Comment: No worries ;)
I don't use twitter much, but I'll go ahead and add you